# Error running Telegram bot "CallbackContext"

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have a problem setting up a bot on another system
My Telegram bot works properly on the system, but gives various errors as soon as it is transferred to another system
All used libraries are installed

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CallbackContext' from 'telegram.ext'
```

Comment: install and upgrade `pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with updating python-telegram-bot(upgrading in Python) you problem would be solved